# "which is not annotated with @Test or not included " , I have tried my best to find a solution for this problem, but there is no result

Tags: java, testng

[image]

[image]

```
public class res {

    @BeforeTest
    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("test1..........");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        System.out.println("test2.........");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "test2")
    public void test3(){
        System.out.println("test3..........");
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "test3")
    public void test4(){
        System.out.println("test4..........");
    }
}
```

Error Log:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: com.ed.st.TestCase.res.test3() is depending on method public void com.ed.st.TestCase.res.test2(), which is not annotated with @Test or not included.
        at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.findDependedUponMethods(MethodHelper.java:111)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.topologicalSort(MethodHelper.java:240)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.sortMethods(MethodHelper.java:317)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.collectAndOrderMethods(MethodHelper.java:59)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:481)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:153)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:522)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
        at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1273)
        at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1260)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1114)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
        at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
```

Comment: Can you share your testNg.xml? As i have executed above code and it executed without any issue. Looks like issue is with your testNg.xml.

Comment: How do you run the tests?

Comment: Any update? I got the same issue.